# Как получить доступ к web?

Tags: php, ubuntu, yii2, access

Клонировал репозиторий, сделал `composer install`, `composer update`вроде се делал правильно, но когда я запускаю проект (не указывая корневой папкой `web`) - система ее не видит (хотя она есть):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сделал `sudo chmod -R 777 /path/to/web`, но ничего не изменилось - папка по прежнему не показывается!

Когда я делаю ее корнем проекта в конфигах  сервера - выбрасывает
 ошибку **"Внутренняя ошибка сервера"**!

**Как правильно настроить, чтоб `web` отображалась?**

*ОС - ubuntu 16.04*

*шаблон - yii2 basic*

Вывод ls -l

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 tarkik tarkik 2226 Авг 28 15:42 composer.json
-rwxrwxr-x 1 tarkik tarkik 826 Авг 28 15:42 Makefile
-rwxrwxr-x 1 tarkik tarkik 1305 Авг 28 15:42 README.md
drwxrwxr-x 2 tarkik tarkik 4096 Авг 28 15:42 runtime
drwxrwxr-x 9 tarkik tarkik 4096 Авг 28 15:40 src
drwxrwxrwx 6 tarkik tarkik 4096 Авг 28 15:42 web
-rwxrwxr-x 1 tarkik tarkik 802 Авг 28 15:38 yii
-rwxrwxr-x 1 tarkik tarkik 515 Авг 28 15:42 yii.bat
```

Comment: покажите вывод `ls -l`

Comment: @5f0f5048ff, добавил к ответу